# Magento2 : How to remove Personal Information from customer account registration page

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, frontend, customer-account

I want to remove this Personal Information block.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override **register.phtml** to your theme

**From**

> vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/register.phtml

**To**

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Customer/templates/form/register.phtml

Now just remove or comment

```
<legend class="legend"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Personal Information') ?></span></legend>
```

**And**

```
<legend class="legend"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Sign-in Information') ?></span></legend><br>
```

Comment: I need to remove First Name, Last Name and Sign Up for Newsletter fields also